# Subclassing ProgressChangedEventArgs problem

Tags: c#, events

I am extending ProgressChangedEventArgs. Below is my code snippet:

```
public class Sample : ProgressChangedEventArgs
{
    public String Something { get; set; }
}
```

This code is throwing the following error:

```
"System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to provide a constructor that takes the same arguments as the constructor of ProgressChangedEventArgs and call the base constructor in your constructor:

```
public Sample(int progressPercentage, Object userState)
    : base(progressPercentage, userState)
{ 
}
```

Comment: If no constructor is specified, shouldn't the class automatically get a constructor that does take 0 arguments?

Comment: Sure. But the base class only has one constructor which requires two parameters. This needs to be called. The automatically generated ctor only calls the default ctor of the base class. This fails, if none exists and leads to the compilation error of the OP.